# Troubleshooting XSLT...trying to alter XML output

Tags: xml, xslt

Ok, so I have this XML data that I'm trying to alter.  I have XSLT written but it's not doing the trick and I need help figuring out what is wrong with it.

Here is my XML that I need to alter using XSLT:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<bb:Report_Data xmlns:bb="urn:com.playdate.report/Absence_Balances-Outbound">
   <bb:Report_Entry>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Sick</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Sick</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
         <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      </bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
      <bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Vacation</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Vacation</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
         <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>3.323077</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      </bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
      <bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Winter Recess</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Winter Recess</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
         <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      </bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>08122012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate2>08262012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate2>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate3>09092012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate3>
                <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </bb:Report_Entry>

</bb:Report_Data>
```

This is what I need it to look like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<bb:Report_Data xmlns:bb="urn:com.playdate.report/Absence_Balances-Outbound">

   <projectedBalanceTotal>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Sick</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Sick</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
         <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>08122012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Vacation</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Vacation</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
         <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>3.323077</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>08122012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Winter Recess</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Winter Recess</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
         <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>08122012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>

   <projectedBalanceTotal>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Sick</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Sick</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
         <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>08262012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Vacation</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Vacation</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
         <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>3.323077</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>08262012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Winter Recess</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Winter Recess</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
         <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>08262012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Sick</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Sick</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
         <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>09092012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>

   <projectedBalanceTotal>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Vacation</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Vacation</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
         <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>3.323077</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>09092012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Winter Recess</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Winter Recess</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
         <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>09092012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>

</bb:Report_Data>
```

This is the XSLT I am using that's not doing the trick:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:wd="urn:com.playdate.report/Projected_Absence_Balances-Outbound">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <bb:Report_Data>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*/*/*[starts-with(local-name(),'projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate')]"/>
 </bb:Report_Data>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
     <xsl:copy-of select="
       ../../bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId      |
       ../bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId          |
       ../bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription    |
       ../bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period" />
     <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
     </bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
     <xsl:copy-of select="../../bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId" />
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It would also be nice if I could remove the WD prefixes.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: LC_123, Please, edit the question and: 1. Provide much shorter XML document. 2. Provide the exact wanted result for this short XML document; 3. Most importantly, explain all the requirements that the transformation must implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you probably first need to start off by matching **bb:Report_Entry** elements

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="bb:Report_Data/bb:Report_Entry"/>
```

Then, for each such entry, you try to match the effective dates

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="*[starts-with(local-name(),'projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate')]"/>
```

And then, within the template that matches the dates, you match **bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker** elements, but passing in the date as a parameter.

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(),'projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate')]">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="../bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker">
      <xsl:with-param name="date" select="."/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

The template for **bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker** could then output the elements within in, along with the effective which was passed as a parameter.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:bb="urn:com.playdate.report/Absence_Balances-Outbound">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <bb:Report_Data>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="bb:Report_Data/bb:Report_Entry"/>
      </bb:Report_Data>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="bb:Report_Entry">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(local-name(),'projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate')]"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(),'projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate')]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker">
         <xsl:with-param name="date" select="."/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker">
      <xsl:param name="date"/>
      <projectedBalanceTotal>
         <xsl:copy-of select="../bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId"/>
         <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
            <xsl:value-of select="$date"/>
         </bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
         <xsl:copy-of select="../bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId"/>
      </projectedBalanceTotal>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bb:Report_Data xmlns:bb="urn:com.playdate.report/Absence_Balances-Outbound">
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Sick</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Sick</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>08122012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Vacation</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Vacation</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>3.323077</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>08122012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Winter Recess</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Winter Recess</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>08122012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Sick</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Sick</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>08262012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Vacation</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Vacation</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>3.323077</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>08262012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Winter Recess</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Winter Recess</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>08262012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Sick</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Sick</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>09092012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Vacation</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Vacation</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>3.323077</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>09092012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1040182074</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>Winter Recess</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>Winter Recess</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>09092012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>0260971</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
</bb:Report_Data>
```

I wasn't entirely sure if you actually wanted to change the namespace or not, so currently the XSLT keeps it the same.

Comment: Thanks Tim C.!  This works like I had hoped it would work.  I know I could have been more clear on my requirements so thanks so much for being patient.  Re: removing the namespace...it's more of a nice to have than a requirement but I have been trying to remove the bb prefixes from my output file.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that strikes me, looking at your stylesheet, is that an undeclared namespace prefix `bb` occurs several times in XPath expressions and in literal result elements.  You declare the prefix `wd` but do not use it; I guess that namespace is the one `bb` should be bound to.

The second thing is that your XML is forcing your XSLT into the performance of unnatural acts; if you have any influence on the design of the vocabulary, you should get rid of the names `projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1` and so on:  strip the sequence numbers (which provide no information and prevent the use of normal XPath expressions) and restructure the elements so no element name has to carry two pieces of information the way these do.

The third thing is that the reason the stylesheet produces no output even after the namespace error is fixed is that the `select` attribute on the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction in the template for / doesn't match anything.

I hope this helps.  Good luck.